# Continious looping in C#

Tags: c#, loops

I recently started on studying C# and I started making simple programs based on a flowchart about jokes (http://prntscr.com/jo656t).

However, when I am on the part of the flowchart about "Do you want to hear another joke?" I'm absolutely clueless how to loop this.

Here's the code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        string Name;

        Console.WriteLine("What is your name? ");
        Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write(Name);
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("What is your age?");
        int Age = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write(Age);
        Console.Clear();

        string[] jokes = new string[] { "Joke1", "Joke2", "Joke3", "Joke4" };
        int upper = jokes.GetUpperBound(0);
        int lower = jokes.GetLowerBound(0);

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int jk = rnd.Next(lower, upper + 1);     

        if (Age >= 16)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hear a joke?"); 
            string option = Console.ReadLine();

            if (option == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(jokes[jk]);
                Console.Read();

                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hear another joke?");
                string option2 = Console.ReadLine();

                int i; 
                if (option2 == "yes")
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = 1;
                }

                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(jokes[jk]);
                    Console.Read();
                } while (i == 0); 
            } 
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Have a nice day, " + Name);
                Console.Read();
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What a pitty! You're too young to hear this joke!");
            Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("Have a nice day, " + Age);
        }
    }
```

I have no idea, as I'm completely stuck at this point and help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [You posted too much code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/). Probably because [you didn't debug](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). You need to [do that first](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would try to rewrite the code so it is more readable, but something like this should work:

```
bool keepTellingJokes = true;    

while (keepTellingJokes) 
{
    // your joke code here

    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hear another joke?");
    string option2 = Console.ReadLine();

    // break out of loop
    if (option2 == "no")
    {
        keepTellingJokes = false;
    } 
}
// code after escaping joke loop
```

Disclaimer: I do not write c# daily.

Answer (score 0):

The flowchart could be subdivided into three main parts:

1. Asking preliminary questions to decide if you should start telling jokes
2. Telling jokes
3. Ending the program

The middle part (from `msgbox "joke()"` to `msgbox "would you like to hear another joke?"`) is coded using a `do` / `while` loop. It would be useful to make it a separate method:

```
private static void TellJokes() {
    bool shouldContinue;
    do {
        shouldContinue = true;
        ... // Tell a joke, ask if they liked it, and ask if they want more
        if (answer == "no") {
            shouldContinue = false;
        }
    } while (shouldContinue);
}
```

Note that you could move printing of `"Have a nice day!"` to the bottom of your program, because all branches end up printing it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int jk;  
    string option;

    if (Age >= 16)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hear a joke?"); 
        option = Console.ReadLine();

        while (option == "yes")
        {
            jk = rnd.Next(lower, upper + 1);    
            Console.WriteLine(jokes[jk]);
            Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hear a joke?"); 
            option = Console.ReadLine();
        } 
        Console.WriteLine("Have a nice day, " + Name);
        Console.Read();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What a pitty! You're too young to hear this joke!");
        Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Have a nice day, " + Age);
    }
```

I suggest taking care about user's answer, you may do something like this

```
do
{
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hear a joke?"); 
        option = Console.ReadLine();
}
while((option.ToLower() != "yes") || (option.ToLower() != "no") )
```